# Android app not running on the emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

The emulator won't launch my apps even on a real device! I've tried every solution online, even reinstalling android sdk,ADT plugin. The app run SOMTIMES(4x to be exact) though, like awhile ago, when i got home i tried it again, and it run on my first try then i began working on the code again then i tried to run it, won't run again. Even basic apps like hello world won't run most of the time. I've set the run configuration to let me choose my device everytime, but even the device chooser wont show up(showed up once only), i tried waiting for 30 minutes(also tried the kill-server start-server) but it just wont run! my real device, or the emulator is listed on the DDMS perspective and there's nothing on console. please help, cause I've wasted 2 days for this already.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try deleting your emulator and creating a new one. Make sure that all your settings are correct and that you are targeting the right OS version.

I've had quite a few problems with the emulator and wiping them and starting from scratch worked more often than not.

As for the real device, the first real hurdle is getting the right drivers so that your PC can recognize it, after that kill-server start-server usually does it. I'm surprise that didn't work for you.

Comment: If the device is synching on my pc, it means i have the appropriate drivers, right? I have htc desire z

Answer (score 0):

Have you also tried, taking the USB cable then disabling debugging and then enabling debugging and putting the USB cable back.

I remember this happen to me, so I did what I mentioned and surprisingly it works. Hope it work for you too.